# How to check for alphanumeric characters

Tags: jquery

I'm writing a custom method for a jQuery plugin:

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("alphanumeric", function(value, element) {
        return this.optional(element) || (/*contains "^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$"*/);
});
```

I know the regexp for what I want, but I'm not sure how to write something in JS that will evaluate to True if it contains the alphanumeric characters. Any help?

Comment: If you change you question, write `EDIT` and describe what you change in you question.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

See [`test`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test) RegExp method.

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("alphanumeric", function(value, element) {
        return this.optional(element) || /^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/.test(value);
});
```

Comment: great answer. I'd suggest using '+' in the regex instead of '*' otherwise an empty string will match

Comment: I agree because optional would handle an empty string.

Comment: This is almost exactly what I want. If I input `qwertyuiop` then it will be true. But I'd also like to input `qwerty uiop` (with a space) and still have it be true. I just don't want a totally blank input even if the amount of blanks exceeds the minimum length. How can I do that?

Comment: `/^[a-zA-Z0-9]+/.test('asdasd123!!!') ==true;` Have to be `/^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/.test(val)` . Forgot `$`

Comment: Hi, I have removed $ to allow whitespace in string. But I could not add whitespace in beginning of the string using this regex(/^[a-zA-Z0-9]+/). Please advice.

Answer (score 7):

If you want to use Spanish chars in your alphanumeric validation you can use this:

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("alphanumeric", function(value, element) {
    return this.optional(element) || /^[a-zA-Z0-9áéíóúÁÉÍÓÚÑñ ]+$/.test(value);
});
```

I also added a blank space to let users add words

Comment: If you want to use more languages you could add French and German chars, but the regex could be to much "heavy". Just use the chars you really would evaluate

Answer (score 6):

You can use regexes in JavaScript:

```
if( yourstring.match(/^[a-zA-Z0-9]+/) ) {
     return true
}
```

Note that I used `+` instead of `*`. With `*` it would return true if the string was empty

Comment: what if you want to add a variable length between two digits and include the validation above? How can you do that?

Comment: @danny_boy you can use curly brackets to specify a length range. So instead of `+` you could do `{2,4}` which would mean "at least 2 but not more than 4 of these characters". Does that answer your question?

Answer (score 4):

```
// use below ... It is better parvez abobjects.com
jQuery.validator.addMethod("postalcode", function(postalcode, element) {
    if( this.optional(element) || /^[a-zA-Z\u00C0-\u00ff]+$/.test(postalcode)){ 
         return false;
    }else{ 
         return this.optional(element) || /^[a-zA-Z0-9]+/.test(postalcode); 
    } 

}, "<br>Invalid zip code");



rules:{
  ccZip:{          
           postalcode : true
       },
       phone:{required: true},

This will validate zip code having no letters but alphanumeric
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("input:text").filter(function() {
    return this.value.match(/^[a-zA-Z0-9]+/);
})
```