# alphanumeric is not working in jquery

Tags: jquery, validation, alphanumeric

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to check for alphanumeric characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5732187/how-to-check-for-alphanumeric-characters)

Hai i validate the password in jquery using alphanumbercic.It validate only the letters,Suppose i typed only the numbers it allowed .Kindly guide me

**problem**

Without using letters it allowed

**coding**

```
letters = /^[0-9a-zA-Z]+$/;   
            if(!password.value.match(letters))   
            {   
                alert('Password must be alphanumeric');   
                signupForm.password.focus();   
                return false;   
            }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your password must contain **all** the cases: capital letters,small letters and numbers, then you need to create 3 regexps:

```
var regexps = [/[A-Z]/,   //capital letter
              /[a-z]/,    //small letter
              /\d/ ];     //numeric digit
//This regexp is for assuring that 
//password does not contain other symbols than alphanumerics
var nonAlphanumericRegExp = /[^0-9a-zA-Z]/;
```

then validate like this:

```
if(regexps.some(function(value){  return !value.test(password.value); }) ||
       nonAlphanumericRegExp.test(password.value)){
    alert('Password must be alphanumeric');   
    signupForm.password.focus();   
    return false; 
}
```

[Live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/S5W2D/1/)

*docs*:

[**Array.some()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)

[**RegExp.test()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test)

Comment: what is some()? then value.test?

Comment: @JavaH See my update, I have slightly changed it.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest, possibly:

```
/([a-z])([0-9])/
```

Which looks to match both a group of `[a-z]` letters, and `[0-9]` numbers.

The problem in your original expression seems to be that it was looking for only *one* group of characters that matched any part of the range identified as being `a-z`, `A-Z` or `0-9`, which would match as true for only-numbers, only-letters or numbers *and* letters.

The above RegExp revised to:

```
/(([a-z])+([0-9]))|(([0-9])+([a-z]))/
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/Qaswd/).

The reason for the change, above, is so that the RegExp will match *both* `a1` and `1a`, using the `|` (RegExp `or`) to match one, or the other, but still return `false` if neither is found and `true` if either is found.

Comment: letters = /^[([a-z])([0-9])]+$/;  is this correct?

Comment: Close, but I'd omit the `^` and the `$`, unless you need the first character to be a letter, and the last to be a number? I've also revised the RegExp, as shown in the answer.

Comment: ITS WORKING ....IT MUST ALLOWS ONE CAPITAL LETTER...I NEED ANY CAPITAL OR SMALL LETTER AND NUMBER

Comment: Please don't SHOUT. If it's not working as required just *say* so, and I'll take a look at that. =)

Comment: cool...am just confused wait i will check