# Additional rules for Jquery .validate()

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I am using JQuery to validate a form and would like to make the chosenUsername field only accept alphanumeric characters without spaces. I can't seem to find a rule to do this though - what can I do?

```
$('.theForm').validate({
        errorElement: 'label', //default input error message container
        errorClass: 'help-inline', // default input error message class
        focusInvalid: false, // do not focus the last invalid input
        ignore: "",
        rules: {
            chosenUsername: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 4
            }
        },

        messages: { // custom messages for radio buttons and checkboxes
            message: {
                required: "Please enter a username of at least 4 characters.",
                minlength: "Minimum of 4 characters."
            }

        },
```

Thank you!
Arbiter

Comment: regular expression....

Comment: I'm avoiding the use of regex outside of the validation plugin, I'm looking to create a rule outside of this snippet, in the jquery validation plugin, so that I can use the rule again and again in any form that is validated using the same jquery plugin. I hope that makes sense, sorry for not being clear.

Comment: You can refer the solutions in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5732187/how-to-check-for-alphanumeric-characters

Comment: You could also include [the plugin's `additional-methods.js` file](http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.13.0/additional-methods.js) and just use its `alphanumeric` rule.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("alphanumeric", function(value, element) {
    return this.optional(element) || /^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/.test(value);
});
```

refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11326910/jquery-validator-validate-alphanumeric-space-and-dash)

Comment: Now that's interesting, I can place this in the JQeury validation library can't I? Making the method accessible to any validation snippet?

Comment: yes,you can do it by writing inside the plugin.

Comment: Instead of writing a custom method, I recommend simply including [the plugin's `additional-methods.js` file](http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.13.0/additional-methods.js) so you can use its `alphanumeric` rule.